# How to generate names correctly?

Tags: python

I am trying to generate five letter names so that they have the format consonant_vowel_consonant_vowel_consonant. Please tell me what I need to do to take a letter first from one array, then from another, etc. alternately?

```
import string
import random

consonants = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q',
              'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']

vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y']


def id_generator(size=5, chars=consonants + vowels):
    return print(''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size)))


id_generator()
```

Comment: If you keep your index in a named variable instead of throwing it away in `_`, you can check whether it's an even number and use that to inform your other logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a toggle state. If a bool is true add vowel, otherwise add consonant.

```
import string
import random

consonants = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q',
              'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']

vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y']


def id_generator(size=5):
    toggle = True
    _id = ""
    for i in range(size):
        if toggle:
            toggle = False
            _id +=  random.choice(consonant)
        else:
            toggle = True
            _id +=  random.choice(vowels)
    print(_id)
    

id_generator()
```

Also, an easier way to assign a list:

```
vowels = list("AEIOU")
```

Comment: You don't really need the `if/else`, you can just do `_id += random.choice(consonants if toggle else vowels)` and then switch the flag with `toggle = not toggle` without any condition. BTW, right now you are starting with vowel, it is asked to start with consonant

Comment: You are right, but i wanted to make it explicit so it is easier to understand. As for consonant coming first, you are right again. I updated the answer.

Comment: `vowels = list("AEIOU")` could even be `vowels="AEIOU"`. It works just as fine.

Answer (score 1):

Save the index of the loop and use it to alternately index a tuple containing the vowels and consonants lists:

```py
import random

consonants = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q',
              'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']

vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y']

chars = (consonants, vowels)

def id_generator(size=5):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars[i % 2]) for i in range(size))

print(id_generator())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can for instance use the rank in the loop to choose between a consonants and vowels, choosing a consonant for the first rank to always start by a consonant :

```
import random

consonants = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q',
              'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']

vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y']

def id_generator(size=5):
  r = ''
  for i in range(0, size):
    r += random.choice(vowels if i & 1 else consonants)
  return r
```

Examples of execution :

```
>>> id_generator()
'SAWYK'
>>> id_generator()
'COPIT'
>>> id_generator()
'XAMYP'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate separately the random consonants and vowels, then interleave them:

```
import more_itertools
def id_generator(size, consonants, vowels):
    vsize = size//2
    csize = size - vsize
    vv = [random.choice(vowels) for _ in range(vsize)]
    cc = [random.choice(consonants) for _ in range(csize)]
    return ''.join((more_itertools.roundrobin(cc,vv)))

>>> id_generator(5, consonants, vowels)
'PASUX'
>>> id_generator(8, consonants, vowels)
'QIWUSUNI'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is like @Demi-Lune's response, except it assigns to slices:

```
import random

consonants = 'BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'
vowels = 'AEIOU'

def id_generator(size, consonants, vowels):
    result = [None] * size
    vsize = size // 2
    csize = size - vsize
    result[:size:2] = random.choices(consonants, k=csize)
    result[1:size:2] = random.choices(vowels, k=vsize)
    return ''.join(result)

id_generator(5, consonants, vowels)
'FOJEF'
```